# Laravel Scout search by model ID

Tags: laravel, search, laravel-scout

Looking for a solution here that allows searching for a model by it's ID. I am using tntsearch and currently it seems all columns added inside of `toSearchableArray()` are searchable except for ID. The following is my Order model

```
    public function toSearchableArray() : array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'client_request' => $this->client_request
       ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the primary key is not searchable by TNTSearch. If you're using the package directly, you can run

`$indexer->includePrimaryKey();`

In scout, you could simply add the id to the `toSearchableArray` method:

```php
public function toSearchableArray() : array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'model_id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'client_request' => $this->client_request
       ];
    }
```